# PrimeNg- p-steps: p-steps-complete and p-steps-incomplete class has been removed from primeng version 11

Tags: primeng

#### Describe the bug

in p-steps completed and incompleted steps should have different styles just to differentiate between them. .It was possbile with primeng9  version with **ui-steps-incomplete  and ui-steps-complete** classes. but after migrating to 11 these classes have been removed. is there any alternate way we could do this?

#### Environment

Windows 10

Angular version: Angular 11

PrimeNG version: 11.4.5

node: 16.10

#### Reproducer

*No response*

#### Angular version

11

#### PrimeNG version

11.4.5

#### Build / Runtime

Angular CLI App

#### Language

ALL

#### Node version (for AoT issues node --version)

16.10

#### Browser(s)

*No response*

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior

[currentbehaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn24W.png)

go to p-steps and try to click next in steps . so that it shifts from step1 to step2, step2 to step3 etc

#### Expected behavior

if the user  completes step1 and goes to steps2
step1(that is already completed should have some colors ie color1, background1 )
active one should have color2, background2
step3 ie next steps (incomplete one's) should have color3, background3

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Q1n.png)